# es6/7 shorthand for assigning properties from object to HTMLElement

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2017

What would be a shorthand for the following:

```
setupIframeConfig(element: HTMLIFrameElement, config: IFrameConfig){
    element.src = config.src;
    element.width = config.width;
    element.width = config.width;
}
```

using rest wont do it because it will create a new object instead of the HTML element reference.

```
element = {...element, ...config}
```

thought maybe destructured assignmnent, but is used for declaring variables.

whats a shorthand es6/7 for this case?

Comment: `Object.keys(config).forEach(key=> element[key]=config[key]);`

Comment: `Object.assign(element, config)` should be good enough here.

Comment: I had an answer where you could attach a custom function to the HTMLElement prototype that would loop through your config object and set those attributes in the HTMLElement, but `Object.assign` seems to already do the job like @spender mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are looking for the least-verbose way of doing this.

Most likely this would be achieved by using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

> The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object.

in your case, the target object is `element` and the only source object here would be `config`:

```
Object.assign(element, config)
```